# Gnome-Terminal Cannot Open Display: Error

Tags: ssh, vps, gnome-terminal, ovh

I connected to an OVH-Cloud VPS Server Via SSH and when I install gnome-terminal and attempt to run the command line

```
gnome-terminal -v
```

It will error out and give me the error:

```
 Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```

I am currently running a Ubuntu Server 20 Gigs SSD, 1 Gig Ram, 1 VCore
Any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

gnome-terminal needs an X server in order to display its window. You
first have to make sure you have one installed on your *local* computer
(the one connected to your monitor and keyboard). Then you have to ask
your ssh client to forward X traffic between the client and the server.
The way to do this depends on the client you are using. With a
command-line client, you typically type

```
ssh -X <user>@<host>
```

With PuTTY, you check the box “Enable X11 forwarding” in the settings
page Connection / SSH / X11.

This should solve your problem, but it begs another question: why would
you want to run gnome-terminal on the server rather than just stick with
the terminal you are already using for typing the command
`gnome-terminal`?